# Causal networks and "local" entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, quantum-gravity, cellular-automaton

On his Opus Maximus, a new kind of Science, Stephen Wolfram suggests that causal networks can create behaviour similar to entanglement because the local structure of space is only an averaged approximation to the behaviour of the structures in the network, and there are many cases of structures ("particles") that are on average far away in space that notwithstanding can still share a few "local" links.

My question is: Are there people currently doing research on this area or it remained just a Wolfram afterthought?

Comment: Does he give a prediction for a concrete physics experiment?

Comment: Too bad. I would like to see a model system.

Comment: Does "Maximus" refer to the philosophical / scientific or physical weight (in kilograms) of the said work? :)

Comment: In the sense of his most talked about, haha

Comment: Stephen Wolfram sent me specifically long texts about this theory by e-mail but he didn't make me join. ;-) It's clearly untrue that the quantum entanglement may be replaced by any similar construction of this kind.

Comment: wolfram has announced new research in the area recently https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/04/finally-we-may-have-a-path-to-the-fundamental-theory-of-physics-and-its-beautiful/